# How to append to PYTHONPATH in Tornado so Handlers can use other libraries?

Tags: web, tornado

I am attempting to start a Tornado web server, but I need the Handlers to be able to import libraries from a custom path.  I cannot simply add sys.path.append('..') when launching Tornado, so how do I do it?

Comment: You can specify $PYTHONPATH in the command line before starting tornado.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/user/py/lib')
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this right you need to assign the `PYTHONPATH` to include the custom directories prior to the starting of the Tornado application.

The way to do this in Linux would be this:

```
PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:<custom path 1>:<custom path 2>:<etc>
```

I'm a bit rusty with Windows, but I believe in windows you would:

**Windows XP**

1. Right click **'My Computer'**
2. Click on **'Properties'**
3. Click on the **'Advanced'** tab
4. Click **'Environment Variables'**
5. In either the **System** or **User Environment Variables** locate the one
   for `PYTHONPATH`. If one doesn't exist, create one in System. Add in
   the new custom path to the `PYTHONPATH`. Make sure you use a ; and not
   a : to separate the paths.

**Windows Vista/7**

1. Right click **'Computer'** under the **'Start Button'**.
2. Click on **'Properties'**
3. Click on **'Advanced system settings'** in the left pane
4. Click on the **'Advanced'** tab
5. Click **'Environment Variables'**
6. In either the **System** or **User Environment Variables** locate the one
   for `PYTHONPATH`. If one doesn't exist, create one in System. Add in
   the new custom path to the `PYTHONPATH`. Make sure you use a ; and not
   a : to separate the paths.